# Using the definition of continuity, prove that F is continuous at each point $b \in \mathbb R$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Here is the question:

Suppose the function F satisfies the property that $F(x+y) = F(x) + F(y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb R$. Suppose also that $F$ is continuous at a point $a \in \mathbb R$. Use the definition of continuity to prove that $F$ is continuous at each point $b\in \mathbb R$.

Here is what I have done so far:

> For $F$ to be continuous for $\forall \space b \in \mathbb R$, $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow b}F(x) =F(b)$
>
> $F$ is continuous at $a \implies \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a} F(x) = F(a)$
>
> $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a}F(x)=\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow0}F(a+h)$
>
> = $\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0}(F(a) + F(h))$
>
> = $F(a) +\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0}F(h)$
>
> = $F(a)$
>
> Now suppose $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow b}F(x)$ exists, then
>
> $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow b}F(x)=\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0}F(b+h)$
>
> = $\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0}(F(b) + F(h))$
>
> = $F(b) +\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0}F(h)$
>
> = $F(b)$
>
> Thus since $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow b}F(x)$ exists, F is continuous for all $b \in \mathbb R$

1) Is this a valid proof?

2) If it is, why can I assume that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow b}F(x)$ exists?

3) If we know that $F$ is continuous for all $a \in \mathbb R$, then why can we not just say since that is true, and we know that $b \in \mathbb R$, let $a = b$, then we have proven it. I know we can't say this, but why can't we?

Comment: 3) The assumption is that $F$ is continuous at $a\in \mathbb{R}$ for some **fixed** and only for this particular fixed point $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: ahhhh i did not read that carefully enough. thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the proof is not valid. You are nowhere using the given continuity at $a$ and you cannot assume that $\lim_{x\to b}F(x)$ exists either.

Hint:
$$
\lim_{h\to0}F(b+h)=\lim_{h\to0}F(b-a+a+h)=
\lim_{h\to0}\bigl(F(b-a)+F(a+h)\bigr)=\cdots
$$

Note: here I *don't* assume the initial limit exists; it's customary to write these “conditional equalities“ and, if at the end we arrive at a limit, we can state they're “actual equalities”. To be picky, one should start from the end and go backwards.

> \begin{align}F(b)&=F(b-a+a)=F(b-a)+F(a)\\&=F(b-a)+\lim_{h\to0}F(a+h)\\&=\lim_{h\to0}\bigl(F(b-a)+F(a+h)\bigr)\\&=\lim_{h\to0}F(b-a+a+h)\\&=\lim_{h\to0}F(b+h)\end{align}

Comment: So does manipulating $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow b}F(x)$ mean that I assume the limit exists, even though I never stated that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow b}F(x) = F(b)$?

Comment: @MarkDodds You can *prove* the limit exists by applying known theorems on limits. I added some comments.

Answer (score 2):

$(1)$ I would say almost. You should note in your first step that you conclude that $\lim_{h\to0}F(h)=0$, which is what you use in the second step.

$(2)$ You don't assume it exists, you show it exists by calculating it!

$(3)$ Because the idea is to find a proof that works for **all** $b\in\mathbb{R}$. Your substitution works for a single $b\in\mathbb{R}$, namely $b=a$.

---

If you want to be super rigorous, in the first step, we can do as follows:

$$F(a)=\lim_{x\to a}F(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}F(a+h)$$

by continuity. It follows that

$$F(a)=\lim_{h\to 0}\left[F(a)+F(h)\right]$$

by the additive property of $F$ (and it guarantees this limit exists).
Now, we also have $F(a)=\lim_{h\to0}F(a)$. It follows from the additive property of limits that $\lim_{h\to0}F(h)$ exists and equals $0$.

---

Now, onto the second step.
We will attempt to calculate $\lim_{x\to b}F(x)$.

Using the additive property of limits and what we concluded from the previous step, it follows from the equation

$$\lim_{x\to b}F(x)=\lim_{h\to0}F(b+h)=\lim_{h\to0}[F(b)+F(h)]$$

that $\lim_{x\to b}F(x)$ exists if and only if $\lim_{h\to0}[F(b)+F(h)]$ exists.
On the other hand, from the previous step we have

$$F(b)= F(b)+\lim_{h\to0}F(h)=\lim_{h\to0}F(b)+\lim_{h\to0}F(h)=\lim_{h\to0}[F(b)+F(h)]$$

where the last step follows from the additive property of limits.

This both shows the existence of $\lim_{h\to0}[F(b)+F(h)]$ (and hence of $\lim_{x\to b}F(x)$, as was pointed out above), and that $\lim_{x\to b}F(x)=F(b)$, which finishes the proof.

Comment: for #2, if i just manipulate the $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow b}F(x)$, am I not assuming it exists then? Since I haven't stated that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow b}F(x) = F(b)$?

Comment: I will try to rephrase this.

Comment: See the edited addendum.